# Presto Sql- Multiple union statements -statement is too large (stack overflow during analysis)

Tags: presto

I am trying to create a presto table Using multiple union all  in sql resulting statement is too large (stack overflow during analysis)

### select
1 as id,
'x' as name
union all
select
2 as id,
'x' as name
union all

### --

select
1000 as id,
'x' as name

Answer (score 0):

Give that `x` appears to be a non-changing static value for name, you could try using a sequence here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT s.n AS id, t.name
    FROM (SELECT 'x' AS name) t
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(sequence(1, 1000)) s(n)
)
```

That being said, if you wanted to stick with your current brute force union approach, you could possibly get the length shorting by removing the `as name` alias in each select.  You only need to specify this alias once, so I am suggesting to try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1 as id, 'x' AS name UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'x' UNION ALL     -- no aliases needed from here onwards
    ...
    SELECT 1000, 'x'
)
```

Comment: 'X' value will change .  I tried removing alias in each select and specified only once. It didn't work.